# AS3 Accessing MovieClip when added to stage on another AS class file

Tags: actionscript-3, class, movieclip

I've tried searching articles on here already and sadly, didn't find anything that helped solve my problem. Sorry if there are articles with the answer I am looking for and I am sure it's a simple answer, I just can't quite get my head around it.

I've got my AS stage document and two AS Class files (MAIN and gameScreen), I am trying to access the 'currentLocation' variable from MAIN inside of the gameScreen.as file.

Everything I try seems to fail and come up with an error.

```
          import Main;
          trace(Main.currentLocation);

          trace(MovieClip(parent).currentLocation);
```

My Error that I am getting:

```
        TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Main$ to flash.display.MovieClip.
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass it to the constructor (class names should start with a capital letter):

```
public function GameScreen (currentLocation:Point)
{
    //...
```

This does not rely on the structure of the display hierarchy (like `.parent` does) that is subject to change.
And it doesn't care about where that variable is defined either (like `root.currentLocation`, `static var` and `.parent` do).

It just says "Hello, I'm a GameScreen and I need the current location. Please give it to me."

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get variables from main swf

```js
var p:MovieClip = this.parent.parent as MovieClip;
trace(p.variableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `currentLocation` variable in the Main class static.

```
public static var currentLocation:int;
```

So that you can access `Main.currentLocation` in the gameScreen class.